# Read all record in sql table using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to read all records from "product" table and create objects from each records.
it only gets one records from the database, any ideas might help ?

```
public IReadOnlyList<Product> Search(string name)
{
    var result = new List<Product>();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product ", conn);
            conn.Open();

            using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            {
                    
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var prod = new Product((int)reader["ID"], (string)reader["Name"],
                    (double)reader["Price"], (int)reader["Stock"], (int)reader["VATID"],
                    (string)reader["Description"]);

                result.Add(prod);
                reader.NextResult();

            }
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
            return result;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why needed `reader.NextResult();`? You have `while` loop on `reader.Read()`.

Comment: You needn't it. `reader.Read()` switches to next record and returns `true` if next record exists. Otherwise `false`, which means there no more records to read.

Comment: If I get rid of it, this error occur : Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *several* result sets, you should *loop* over them, i.e. you should put one more outer loop, e.g.

```
using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

do {
  while (reader.Read()) {
    var prod = new Product(
      Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]), 
      Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]),
      Convert.ToDouble(reader["Price"]), // decimal will be better for money
      Convert.ToInt32(reader["Stock"]), 
      Convert.ToInt32(reader["VATID"]),
      Convert.ToString(reader["Description"])
    );

    result.Add(prod); 
  }
}
while (reader.NextResult());
```

Note outer `do .. while` loop since we always have at least one result set.

Comment: YES, thank you this works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

You use [`NextResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) which advances the reader to the next result set. This makes sense if you have multiple sql queries and you'd use it after the while-loop. Here it's just unnecessary and wrong.

You are already advancing the reader to the next **record** with [`Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

> If I get rid of it, this error occur : Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String.

You can use [`IsDBNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0):

```
int nameIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Name");
string name = reader.IsDBNull(nameIndex) ? null : reader.GetString(nameIndex);
int descIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Description");
string description = reader.IsDBNull(descIndex) ? null : reader.GetString(descIndex);

var prod = new Product((int)reader["ID"], 
                       name, 
                       (double)reader["Price"], 
                       (int)reader["Stock"], 
                       (int)reader["VATID"], 
                       description);
```

Use it for every nullable column, for the numeric columns you could use nullable types like `int?`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code:
Remove the line  `reader.NextResult();`

NextResult is used for moving to next result set not next record.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely remove the `NextResult()`. That does **NOT** move between individual records in the same query. `Read()` does this for you already. Rather, `NextResult()` allows you to include multiple queries in the same `CommandText` and run them all in one trip to the database.

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> Search(string name)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product ", conn))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) )
        {
           command.CommandText += " WHERE Name LIKE @Name + '%'";
           command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = name;
        }

        conn.Open();
        using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        {                    
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var prod = new Product((int)reader["ID"], reader["Name"].ToString(),
                    (double)reader["Price"], (int)reader["Stock"], (int)reader["VATID"],
                    reader["Description"].ToString());

                yield return prod;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okey, I removed it but still "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String" error occurs.

Comment: Then you need to add code to the `new Product()` section to look for those `NULL` values. Also, the `Price` value should be `decimal` rather than `double`. **NEVER** use `double` for money.